# Reveal.js left and right arrows should navigate width keyboard and keep the ID's next to it

Tags: jquery, reveal.js

My DEMO shows the navigation arrows navigate correctly ON CLICK but also with the (keyboard)cursor.

- The LEFT and RIGHT need to have the name of the section ID next to it!
- Works clicking the arrows
- Doesn't work with the keyboard `(e.keyCode == 37)(e.keyCode == 39)`

[Reveal.js](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js)

- Also I want to appent the ID on left and right arrow.

  `$('.navigate-right').html('<h3> '+  $(this).text(prevId) +' </h3>');`

http://jsfiddle.net/3fJqZ/100/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `slidechanged` event to get what you are looking for:

```
Reveal.addEventListener( 'slidechanged', function( event ) {
    var currentSection = $('section.present');
    var nextId = currentSection.next('section').attr('id');

    $('.navigate-left').text($(event.previousSlide).attr('id'));

    $('.navigate-right').text(nextId);
} );
```

Working Plunkr here: http://jsfiddle.net/3fJqZ/109/